# Configuring Apache subdomain for Redmine

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have a server called DEV01.intranet where I have installed Redmine.

I managed to configure a subdomain redmine.dev01.intranet, which is working now, but when I go to dev01.intranet alone it shows Redmine again (??!!!)

I would like to access Redmine from http://redmine.dev01.intranet and http://dev01.intranet/redmine.

I have these in sites-enabled:

GNU nano 2.2.6                             File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

GNU nano 2.2.6                             File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/redmine

```
<VirtualHost redmine.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar:80>
 ServerName redmine.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar
 DocumentRoot /usr/local/share/redmine/public
 ServerAlias redmine.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar
 ServerAdmin jsivil@fusiondev.com.ar
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_access combined
 RailsEnv production
 RailsBaseURI /redmine
 PassengerDefaultUser www-data
 PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
 <Directory /var/www/redmine>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What I am doing wrong and why is Redmine shown at root / when no one says so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came around the solution.

The bigges problem solved adding 000-xxx, 001-xxx (number prefix) to VirtualHosts symbolic links from sites-available to sites-enabled. That way the dev01 alone will load first, then redmine.dev01.

Last, I had no CSS in the second Redmine to load. If I go to redmine.dev01 first after Apache restart, it loads OK. But de01/redmine wont have CSS, and viceversa if I load it first.

The solution was to make a copy of the source folder and point the subdomain DocumentRoot's to the second folder. It's like a new instance. Didn't search too much for other solutions, but since the DB is the same, it's only 60mb of wasted disk space and a second instance in memory (If that's the way Ruby on Rails manages it).

My VirtualHosts, in case anyone needs a hand.

GNU nano 2.2.6                             File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-dev01

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin jsivil@fusiondev.com.ar
        ServerName dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar
        ServerAlias www.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev01
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/dev01>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/dev01/redmine>
                RailsBaseURI /redmine
                PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

GNU nano 2.2.6                          File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-redmine.dev01

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName redmine.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar
 DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine.dev01/redmine
 ServerAlias www.redmine.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar
 ServerAdmin jsivil@fusiondev.com.ar
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_access combined
 RailsEnv production
 RailsBaseURI /redmine
 PassengerDefaultUser www-data
 PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
 <Directory /var/www/redmine.dev01/redmine>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to exhange:

```
<VirtualHost redmine.dev01.intranet.fusiondev.com.ar:80>
```

with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

VirtualHosts and IP addresses are somewhat tricky - look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I've found the answer. Can you vote up my question so I can put it? Requires 10 reputation and I have 9. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - voted you up :)